# Setting up Vagrant to mirror a heroku instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, virtualbox, vagrant

I am ramping up on [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) and was wondering if there was a walkthrough / recipe to get a vagrant instance up and running to mirror a heroku bamboo stack (lenny 5.0 ree-1.8.7)

I am stuck on the first step of trying to find a lenny box.

Thanks guys,

Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting Heroku's Cedar stack, you can try [vagrant-heroku](https://github.com/ejholmes/vagrant-heroku).  I'm not sure what options exist for Aspen and Bamboo, but I would suspect that they may exist.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to build and package the box yourself. There are instructions on how to do this here: http://www.owengriffin.com/posts/2010/05/01/Vagrant_for_Debian_testing.html

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [veewee](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee).

It makes building base boxes for Vagrant much simpler. There is even a template for Debian Lenny you can start with.